# check/uncheck all checkboxes with jquery 1.10.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

There are quite a few questions asked on this topic, but none worked for my problem as I don't know how to apply them in my code - I'm new to jQuery.

Here is my HTML page:

```
<div id="one">
   <div id="positionable2">
      <div id="xyz2">
         <table id="tab1">
           <tr><td class="header"><input type=checkbox id=cbselectall /></td></tr>
           <tr><td ><input type=checkbox name=case /></td></tr>
           <tr><td ><input type=checkbox name=case /></td></tr>
           <tr><td ><input type=checkbox name=case /></td></tr>
         </table>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Now my jQuery looks something like below:

```
$(function () {
    $("#one #positionable2 #xyz2 #tab1 #cbselectall").click(function () {
        if ($("#one #positionable2 #xyz2 #tab1 #cbselectall").is(':checked')) {
            $("#one #positionable2 #xyz2 #tab1 input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
                //$(this).attr("checked", true);
                $(this).prop("checked", true);
            });

        } else {
            $("#one #positionable2 #xyz2 #tab1 input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
                //$(this).attr("checked", false);
                $(this).prop("checked", false);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Please note that I have other columns in the table, the column with checkbox is the first column. Upon clicking the checkbox in the table header, other columns on data row should get selected and vice versa. Somehow this is not working.

As I'm new to jQuery, somehow I'm unable to make it work. Please help.

Comment: A jsfiddle would help.

Comment: What's the problem, your code is working fine. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RCZZ4/

Comment: In my page with entire page contents, it's not working. When i click t he header checkbox, the other checkboxes are not getting selected.

Comment: My table with checkboxes is loaded after one of the other table is loaded. My jquery is in <head> SECTION OF HTML PAGE. Is there something i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are your checkboxes created dynamically using Javacript or Ajax after page load?

Comment: Maybe you have a syntax error in your code. Open up the browser's development console after loading your HTML page and look for any reported errors.

Comment: Yes, they are dynamically loaded after the first table is loaded. Is it causing the issue?

Comment: I don't see any syntax errors ... i'm using firefox - firebug to see any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first off you don't need to specify the heirarchy in each of your selectors.

```
$("#cbselectall").on('click', function() {

    $(this)
    .parents('table') // go to the table element
    .find(':checkbox') /* find all checkboxes (note you might need to specifiy 
                          if you have other checkboxes in the table that shouldn't get checked 
                       */
    .prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked')); /* set the checked value to be the value
                                                 of the check all checkbox */
})
```

Comment: It's not working. The table with checkboxes are dynammically loaded after first table is loaded. Is it causing problem? Please help.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It worked. I need to put this jquery in callback function of ajax call where these are loaded dynamically. Thank you.