# jquery 1.10.2 bulk select checkboxes, callback error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I read [check/uncheck all checkboxes with jquery 1.10.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22161254/check-uncheck-all-checkboxes-with-jquery-1-10-2#) and he mentioned not putting the function in the proper callback.  I debugged in chrome dev tools and noticed the checkbox listeners don't get hit after I add a row using my other jquery function.

According to jquery "ready" docs, document.ready's callback gets triggered when the DOM is done loading.  After adding a row through my jquery handler, the DOM has finished loading, that's how I see the new row.  So to my understanding I should be able to have my checkbox listeners in the "ready" callback, no?  Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var i = 1;
        $("#add_row").click(function() {
            $('#addr' + i).html("<td><input type='checkbox' class='form-control case'></td>"  + 

                                "<td><input name='name" + i + "' type='text' placeholder='Name' " +
                                "class='form-control input-md'></td>" +

                                "<td><input name='mail" + i + "' type='text' placeholder='Mail' " +
                                "class='form-control input-md'></td>"

                                );

            $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr' + (i + 1) + '"></tr>');
            i++;
        });

        $("#delete_btn_" + i).click(function(event) {
            if (i > 1) {
                $("#addr" + (i - 1)).html('');
                i--;
            }
        });


        // add multiple select / deselect functionality
        $("#selectall").click(function () {
            $('.case').prop('checked', this.checked);
        });

        /* Listen to any checkbox.  After one is toggled,
           if all checkboxes are selected, select the checkall checkbox
           otherwise checkall checkbox shouldn't be checked */
        $(".case").click(function() {
            if($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
                $("#selectall").prop("checked", "checked");
            } else {
            $("#selectall").removeProp("checked");
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: why cant i answer my own question?  I discovered the error wasn't just in the "click" vs "on" event binding.  There's something else you need  for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("body").on('change','.case',function() {
        if($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
            $("#selectall").prop("checked", "checked");
        } else {
            $("#selectall").removeProp("checked");
        }
    });
```

Comment: hmm, copied and pasted this and it didn't work.